# Summery table lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript-controller

I am trying to built a summery or pivot table in lightning component. Currently I am getting repeated values inside my table, not the actual ones.
Response inside .js is like this:

```
{
    "Short Range": {
        "2018": {
            "QtyInvoiced": 400,
            "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
            "TotalValueUSDList": 0
        },
        "2019": {
            "QtyInvoiced": 940,
            "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
            "TotalValueUSDList": 0
        }
    },
    "Services": {
        "2018": {
            "QtyInvoiced": 44,
            "TotalContributionUSDList": 218.04,
            "TotalValueUSDList": 218.04
        },
        "2020": {
            "QtyInvoiced": 13,
            "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
            "TotalValueUSDList": 0
        }
    },
    "Positioning": {
        "2021": {
            "QtyInvoiced": 222,
            "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
            "TotalValueUSDList": 0
        }
    }
}
```

My ideal table is like this one where most left column, year row at top and values inside them are dynamic(can be changed) against 3 fields:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given your original data, you want to transform it into something you can iterate over. This will be a collection of objects and arrays. Given your original data, I transformed it into this:

```
[
    {
        "key": "Short Range",
        "sums": [
            {
                "year": "2018",
                "QtyInvoiced": 400,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            },
            {
                "year": "2019",
                "QtyInvoiced": 940,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            },
            {
                "year": "2020",
                "QtyInvoiced": 0,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            },
            {
                "year": "2021",
                "QtyInvoiced": 0,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "Services",
        "sums": [
            {
                "year": "2018",
                "QtyInvoiced": 44,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 218.04,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 218.04
            },
            {
                "year": "2019",
                "QtyInvoiced": 0,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            },
            {
                "year": "2020",
                "QtyInvoiced": 13,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            },
            {
                "year": "2021",
                "QtyInvoiced": 0,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "Positioning",
        "sums": [
            {
                "year": "2018",
                "QtyInvoiced": 0,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            },
            {
                "year": "2019",
                "QtyInvoiced": 0,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            },
            {
                "year": "2020",
                "QtyInvoiced": 0,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            },
            {
                "year": "2021",
                "QtyInvoiced": 222,
                "TotalContributionUSDList": 0,
                "TotalValueUSDList": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This took just a few steps. First, we start with our data, which we'll just call `data`. From there, we want to extract all the unique years:

```
let years = [
  ...new Set(
    Object.values(data)
      .map((value) => Object.keys(value))
      .flat()
  ),
];
```

Working through this, it goes like this:

First, `Object.values(data)` takes the values from the top-level data (Short Range, Services, etc), giving us an array of 2018: {...}, 2019:{...}, etc.

Next, `.map((value) => Object.keys(value))` extracts just the keys, giving us a nested array of `[ [2018, 2019], [2018, 2020], [2021] ]`.

After that, `.flat()` converts the multidimensional array to just a flat array: `[2018, 2019, 2018, 2020, 2021]`.

Now, we remove the duplicates with `new Set(...)`, giving us a `Set([2018, 2019, 2020, 2021])`. However, we can't use this set in the way we want to, so we use the rest operator, `...` to copy the Set to an array (`[...value]` is for arrays, `{...value}` for objects).

Finally, to line them up in order, we'll sort them:

```
years.sort();
```

Having this, we can now do the main logic:

```
this.output = Object.keys(data).map((key) => ({
  key,
  sums: this.years.map((year) => ({
    year,
    ...(data[key][year] || {
      QtyInvoiced: 0,
      TotalContributionUSDList: 0,
      TotalValueUSDList: 0,
    }),
  })),
}));
```

Here, we take the keys from the data object, and for each key, we iterate for each year, taking the value from the original map, or zero values if there is a gap (this is optional, but included here).

Finally, we just write up our template to match this output:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
            <th for:each={years} for:item="year" key={year}>
                {year}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template for:each={output} for:item="item">
            <tr key={item.key}>
                <th rowspan=3>{item.key}</th>
                <td>Sum of Qty Invoiced</td>
                <td for:each={item.sums} for:item="sum" key={sum.year}>
                    {sum.QtyInvoiced}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr key={item.key}>
                <td>Sum of Total Contribution (USD)</td>
                <td for:each={item.sums} for:item="sum" key={sum.year}>
                    {sum.TotalContributionUSDList}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr key={item.key}>
                <td>Sum of Total Value (USD)</td>
                <td for:each={item.sums} for:item="sum" key={sum.year}>
                    {sum.TotalValueUSDList}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `thead` is generated by the headers for an arbitrary number of years. The `tbody` iterates over each row, and then each year in that row.

And that's about it. This is a rather verbose example, but there's nothing terribly exciting going on.

For further reading, I suggest learning about:

- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (...)
- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `() => {}`
- [Object shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

And, of course, one final piece.

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/dLpzhvfftvvh0PRlrPrW/src/app.html?p=stories).